# How to read a csv row wise and convert to a dataframe column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataset CSV file is row-wise:

```
1,2,3,4
1000,2000,3000,4000
```

I want to read this file and get a dataframe output of two columns, 'index and value'.

Output:

```
index value
1      1000
2      2000
3      3000
```

If I want to get only the 'value' column, I should be able to retrieve them by doing `df['value']`

I tried going about it like this:

```
series = pd.read_csv('file.csv',index_col=0, header=0)
df= series.T
Frame=pd.DataFrame([df], columns = ["index","value"])
```

But this yields an error:

```
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (2, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
df=pd.read_csv('input.csv',header=None)
print df.T.rename(columns={0:'Index',1:'Value'})
print df['Value']
```

Out:

```
0    1000
1    2000
2    3000
3    4000
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Throwing a `KeyError: 'Value'` when I print df['Value'].

Comment: @AmoghMishra - I'm not getting any key error. can you show your df before accessing df['Value']? this may rename doesn't work as expected

Comment: yeah, my df is not returning a similar result. I don't get `Name: Value, dtype: int64` in the end.
 Just to add more information, shape of df before transposing is (1,166) and after transposing (166,1)

Comment: @AmoghMishra- shape after transpose it will be like that only. It would be great if you print the result after transpose.

Comment: This is the output of the df that I am getting
`0    1000
1    2000
2    3000
3    4000
...   ...
166 166000
[166 rows x 1 columns]`

Comment: As per your sample input it should contains 2 columns. Please update proper sample input

Comment: @AmoghMishra- could you upload a file so that I can take a deep look into that

Comment: Shape is correct.[166 rows x 1 columns] means 167 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: @AmoghMishra - It's really confusing me. please upload a file

Comment: file link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LSeUCygCTMzP23-xH-UMohredl1-zKpAr09HTy_81I0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173388/discussion-between-mohamed-thasin-ah-and-amogh-mishra).